# Как сделать цикл на парсинг текста? python + selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Делаю бота для MonkeyType на Python + Selenium, бот должен парсить текст и водить в поле - но через не которое время он останавливается, пробовал все но не получалось это исправить. код:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

keyboard = Controller()

words = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("word")

for word in words:

    keyboard.type(word.text)
            
    # Press space
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.1, 0.2))
    keyboard.press(Key.space)
    keyboard.release(Key.space)
    time.sleep(random.uniform(0.2, 0.3))
```

Comment: ну правильно, как только в words заканчиваются word, то цикл завершается

Comment: Там появляются новые дивы с классом word

Comment: Ну появляется и появляется. Читается-то только один раз в самом начале.

Comment: Лучше через сам selenium кликать на элементы, ведь клик проходит при фокусе на окно. Пример написания текста и отправки Ctrl + Return: https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/5f333adc169490c9d3d031f929f00c3a9e222ed9/selenium__examples/send_message__vk.com/main.py#L73

Comment: Похоже, вам нужно зацикливать код, раз появляются новые элементы, на которые нужно реагировать